# VC++ WINAPI Form: Identifier Not Found (C3861 Error)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm working on a port from some old Delphi code to VC++ 2013, and I'm encountering an error that I feel should be an easy fix but cannot for the life of me figure out...

The problem is this: I have a number of common utility functions in a local file Utils.h that I am deploying as part of a windows form. Most (90%) of the functions in this header work as normal. GetMsg(...), however, throws a C3861 Identifier not found error...

Utils.h (snippet): GetMsg declared at bottom

```
#pragma once

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*
  Includes:
*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

using namespace std;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*
  Constants:
*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define GET_MSG_TIMEOUT 2


/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*
  Typedefs, Structs, Enums:
*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
typedef union
{
   unsigned long  ui32;
   unsigned char  ui8[4];
} UI32_UI8;

typedef union
{
   unsigned short ui16;
   unsigned char  ui8[2];
} UI16_UI8;

typedef union
{
   float f;
   unsigned char  ui8[4];
} F_UI8;

typedef struct
{
   string sName;
   string sVersion;
   string sCompany;
   string sCopyright;
} PRODUCT_INFORMATION;


/*------------------------------------------------------------------------*
  Prototypes:
*------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
unsigned short SwapShort(unsigned short aShort);
float SwapFloat(float aFloat);
unsigned long SwapLong(unsigned long aLong);
unsigned int ReadLine(unsigned char *msgBuf, SerialPort^ Hdl, bool ReturnLF);
void  __stdcall FillTheBuffer(char *buf, String sss, int length);
string  __stdcall FillTheString(string sss, int length);
unsigned int __stdcall GetMsg(SerialPort^ Hdl, unsigned char *msgBuf);
```

GetMsg Definition in Utils.cpp:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int __stdcall GetMsg(SerialPort^ Hdl, unsigned char *msgBuf)
{
  ...
}
```

And, finally, GetMsg usage in form file:

```
#include "Utils.h"

...

void MainForm::UploadButton_Click
     (System::Object^ object, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{

...

SwapShort(1); //Works fine, also declared in Utils.h
GetMsg(spCom, inBuf); //C3861 ERROR

...

}
```

Where spCom is a (SerialPort^) contained, configured, and opened within the windows form. inBuf is a simple array of characters (char*) to buffer the input. I've tried renaming the function, thinking that there may have been an unintentional conflict / overload in other files, to no avail.

Any advice? Thanks, in advance

Comment: @KenWhite Well in C++/CLI it's a managed reference

Comment: I am missing the declaration for SerialPort

Comment: @Vinzenz: Thanks. I don't do anything in C++/CLI, so I waan't aware of that use.

Comment: You should post your solution as an actual answer so that the question doesn't appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem -- As it turns out I needed to be more explicit in my function definitions. Changing the declaration to read

```
GetMsg(System::IO::Ports::SerialPort^ Hdl, unsigned char *msgBuf)
```

eliminated the C3861 error. It would seem that the lack of a specific namespace on the declaration passed Intellisense but confused the compiler, rendering it unable to determine which prototype to use with the function call.